# Can we be cursed by another person?

Tags: lanat

I have been having problems with my family recently, mostly stemming from my brother's new wife who has, since her marriage, become increasingly antagonistic toward us.

It is now at the point where she is outright cursing me and my family — while she is reciting the Qur'an, no less — and even my own brother has started to turn away from us.  I am worried that these curses may actually be taking effect and causing discord between us.

I know that cursing does exist in Islam; there are mentions of the curse of Allah being upon various peoples in both the Qur'an and in the Sunnah.  What I am unsure about is whether or not these curses can be invoked by anybody.

Is my concern valid; do my sister-in-law's curses have any power over us?  How can I be sure that my brother and I (and the rest of my family) are not under a curse?

Comment: Sorry Poppy Bibi.  While your question is interesting and important to you, it is not a good fit for the StackExchange question and answer format. Please read the [faq] I would suggest meeting with an Imam to help you with this matter.

Comment: I would echo Dan Andrews' advice above and suggest that the best course of action for you is to see a scholar that you trust about this. Unfortunately this question as it stands is not a good fit for our website, which aims to build a high-quality repository of information about *Islam*. I wish you and your family the very best.

Comment: The Stack Exchange model works best with more generalized questions that can be of benefit to more future users; I have taken the liberty of seriously reworking this question to better fit our site.  Please review to make sure I have not lost the gist of your post.

Comment: @goldPseudo I considered reworking the question to be more about "curses" rather than this specific situation but decided against it since the question is really about this specific situation, and the answer to the "power of curse" question will be specific to this situation.

Comment: I don't know about curses, but I think you should remain on the right path and be pious and patient. Then Allah will give you justice, even if the whole world curses you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a concept of cursing in Islam. The curse of a weak person, or oppressed or similar people are more likely to create impact on others. (This is based on many reliable Hadith)

> Is my concern valid; do my sister-in-law's curses have any power over us?

This is beyond our scope to answer. Well, if you're the bad person, and if she turns out to be the good person, then

> Indeed, those who have tortured the believing men and believing women and then have not repented will have the punishment of Hell, and they will have the punishment of the Burning Fire. (Qur'an 85:10)

But if it turns out that your the good person and she is the bad one, then trust the creator. He is the ultimate protector.

> How can I be sure that my brother and I (and the rest of my family) are not under a curse?

Well this is not a medical exam by which you can make sure whether or not your under a curse. Once curse has been passed, now it becomes the matter of Ghaib(unseen), and hence beyond our scope to know that.

**Tip:** You can try reciting Surah Al-Falaq from the bottom of your heart.

> Say, "I seek refuge in the Lord...From the evil of that which He created..And from the evil of the blowers in knots, And from the evil of an envier when he envies." ([Qur'an 113](http://quran.com/113))

May the creator guide us all.